# What's the difference between getByText vs findByText vs queryByText in testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-testing-library

There are multiple ways of getting an element's text content: `getByText` vs `findByText` vs `queryByText`.
 Sometimes I get confused about which one to use.
 I have the following example in react-native:

```js
it('should render children', () => {
  const mockedChildComponentTxt = 'Children are rendered';
  const { getByText, findByText, queryByText } = render(
    <MyProvider>
      <div>{mockedChildComponentTxt}</div>
    </MyProvider>,
  );
  expect(queryByText(mockedChildComponentTxt)).toBeTruthy()
});
```

`queryByText` and `getByText` are failing, but `findByText` works.

`debug()` resulting in:

```js
<RNCSafeAreaView
    onInsetsChange={[Function anonymous]}
    style={
      Object {
        "flex": 1,
      }
    }
>
    <div>
      Children are rendered
    </div>
</RNCSafeAreaView>
```

Why `findByText` works in the above example, but `getByText` and `queryByText` fail?

Comment: queryBy vs getBy: 

`getBy` throws an error if the element is not found, while `queryBy` returns null if the element is not found. So, if you're checking for the presence of an element that might not be there, use `queryBy`. If you're certain the element should exist and want the test to fail if it doesn't, use `getBy`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### findBy

> `findBy` queries return a promise which resolves when a matching element is found. The promise is rejected if no elements match or if more than one match is found after a default timeout of 1000 ms. If you need to find more than one element, then use `findAllBy`.

#### getBy

> `getBy` queries return the first matching node for a query, and throw an error if no elements match or if more than one match is found. If you need to find more than one element, then use `getAllBy`.

#### queryBy

> `queryBy` queries return the first matching node for a query, and return null if no elements match. This is useful for asserting an element that is not present. This throws if more than one match is found (use `queryAllBy` instead).

[docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api-queries)

Here in your example  the rendered component contains the text "Children are rendered," but it seems that it might not be available in the DOM immediately.
it's possible that the element is added to the DOM asynchronously after rendering, which is why `getByText` and `queryByText` are not able to find it immediately. however, `findByText` works because it waits for the element to appear in the DOM due to its asynchronous nature

> `findBy` queries return a **promise** which resolves when a matching element is found.

and when it finds the element, the test passes.

Comment: Hi @Hatana, thank you for the answer, can you please explain why getByText doesn't work in my example given above?

Comment: @IsmoilShokirov have a look